# linq query list of guids

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to query the aspnet membership tables and get a list of emails for all users in a specific app that can be in a list of roles.  I'm passing in a list of guids for the roles.  If I take out the line with && r.RoleId in, the rest of the query works, but I'm trying to figure out how to query a list of Guids for role Ids.

```
    from m in Aspnet_Memberships
    join u in Aspnet_Users on m.UserId equals u.UserId
    join ur in Aspnet_UsersInRoles on u.UserId equals ur.UserId
    join r in Aspnet_Roles on ur.RoleId equals r.RoleId
    join a in Applications on r.WebApplicationID equals a.ApplicationId
    where a.ApplicationId == new Guid("55555555-4444-3333-2222-111111111111")  
    && r.RoleId in rolesList //rolesList is a List<Guid>
    select new  {
        m.Email, 
        u.UserName,
        a.ApplicationName,
        r.RoleName
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Contains`

```
rolesList.Contains(r.RoleId)
```

Comment: when I switch from linqpad to visual Studios, I can't join aspnet_usersInRoles because it doesn't show up as an entity, just an association, do you know how to fix that?